# Suppose $\theta \neq \frac pq * \pi$. Show ${\{e^{in\theta} : n \ \epsilon \ N}\}$ is dense in $S^1=\{x + iy: x^2 + y^2 = 1\} \subseteq C$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Essentially, I need to show that e^inx is dense in the complex unit circle for irrational angle x. I'm not sure how to go about this but I think I need to show that between any two points on the unit circle, we can find some e^inx.

Comment: see here and probably lots of other places as well: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282102/prove-that-the-orbit-of-an-iterated-rotation-of-0-by-api-a-irrational-aro

Comment: Full discussions in either of two inexpensive book by Ivan Niven. In *Irrational Numbers,* page 72 Theorem 6.3, he shows that the multiples of an irrational are dense and uniformly distributed n the unit interval ( we are taking the fractional parts). In *Diophantine Approximations,* an entire chapter, pages 24-25 has this thing, Theorem 3.2

Comment: Welcome to the site! You may not have realized that this is a completely common homework problem (and a well known fact about irrational rotations) that has been discussed many times before.   Separately, we have some written advice about "How to ask a good question" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question .

Answer (score -3):

Its so simple.$$exp(jx)=cos(x)+jsin(x)$$. Since $$sin^2(x)+cos^2(x)=1$$ this complex number always is on the circumference of a circle with radius 1

Comment: This doesn't price that irrational rotations are dense on the circle.