# Let $a\in\mathbb{C}, |a|=1$ and $c$ an irrational real number. Prove: $a^c$ is dense in the unit circle.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ a complex number such that $|a|=1$ and $c$ an irrational real number.

> Prove: The set $a^c$ is dense in the unit circle.

The problem is taken from Notes on Complex Function Theory by Donald Sarason.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What is $a^c$? For instance, what is $i^\pi$?

Comment: Can assuming $a = \cos \theta +i \sin \theta = e^{i \theta}$ help?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $a^c=e^{clog(a)}$

Comment: And what is $\log(a)$?

Comment: This is equivalent to the statement in real numbers:  If $x$ is irrational and $a,b\in [0,1]$ be any two real numbers, $nx-[nx]$ (where [y] is the greatest integer less than or equal to $y$) lies between $a$ and $b$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$ ...

Can you prove this statement? The equivalence carries forward quite easily after that.

Comment: You've written this like $a$ and $c$ are fixed. Please clarify the set which is to be dense.

Comment: @halrankard $a$ and and $c$ are indeed fixed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos $log(a)=ln|a|+i(Arg(a)+2\pi n)=i(Arg(a)+2\pi n)$

Comment: @BulGali you still need to specify the set that you want to be dense in the unit circle. Maybe you mean the set $\{a^{nc} \mid n\in \mathbb{N}, a,c \text{ given as above}\}$?

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 $a^c$ is defined as $a^c=e^{clog(a)}$ and  $log(a)= ln|a|+i(Arg(a)+2\pi n) , n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a set.

Comment: Um.. what if $a = 1$?  Also the wording is screwed up: "Let a∈C **a** complex number such that |a|=1 and c **an** irrational real number".  Then the set $\{a^c\}$ contains one single element and is not dense in anything but itself.

Comment: @fleablood Going by similar questions asked in the previous comments, the question looks to be about the set I put in my answer. But I agree that the original post needs these clarifications.

Comment: "a and and c are indeed fixed"  Then the statement is utterly false.  There is only one point in the set $\{a^c\}$ and if you take any other point  and let a radius be anything less than the distance between $a^c$ and the point, the neighborhood of that point will not contain any point $\{a^c\}$ and and so no other points can belong to a set that is dense in $\{a^c\}$.

Comment: @fleablood The point seems to be to not fix a choice of log when defining $a^c$ which produces a set. I updated my answer with these remarks. (Though yes...I agree this should be made clear in the initial question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c$ and $a$ be fixed as in the question. For *any* complex number $w$ with $|w|=1$ define
$$
S_w:=\{w\exp(2\pi i nc):n\in\mathbb{N}\}
$$

According to your specifications if $s=Arg(a)$ then the set you are asking about is precisely $S_w$ where we choose $w=\exp(ics)$.

However we can show $S_w$ is dense for *any* choice of $w$ on the unit circle. There are two steps.

1. Show $S_1$ is dense (details below).
2. Given arbitrary $w$, write $S_w=w\cdot S_1$. So $S_w$ is a uniform rotation of the dense set $S_1$ and hence is dense itself.

To do step 1, this is the usual "irrational rotation". There are many sources with this proof. Here are two from the network

[Dense set in the unit circle- reference needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569152/dense-set-in-the-unit-circle-reference-needed)

[Prove that the orbit of an iterated rotation of 0 (by (A)(Pi), A irrational) around a circle centered at the origin is dense in the circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282102/prove-that-the-orbit-of-an-iterated-rotation-of-0-by-api-a-irrational-aro)

Added later: In light of the comments below the question, I can help clarify. While $a$ and $c$ are fixed, the intention seems to be to *not* fix a branch of logarithm, leading to a *set* of values for $a^c=\exp(c\log(a))$, in which $\log(a)$ takes any value $i(Arg(a)+2\pi n)$ as $n$ ranges over natural numbers.
Since $c$ is irrational we obtain a countable set of values, and this is the set of values that one wants to show is dense. In other words

> If $z$ is an irrational number, then the countably infinitely many choices of $\log w$ lead to infinitely many distinct values for $w^z$.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Complex_exponents_with_complex_bases

Note that if $a=1$ then formally one can still obtain a set of values in the same way, which would be the set $S_1$ above. Though this is abusing the notation of complex exponentiation.

Comment: Why is it enough to consider the case where $w=1$?

Comment: I have added some detais