# If $|w|=1$ and $w^n$≠1 for any $n \in \mathbb{N}_+$, show that $ \{w^n ; n \in \mathbb{N}_+\}$ is dense in ∂$\Bbb D$.

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem is that in the title:

> If $|w|=1$ and $w^n\not=1$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}_+$, show that $\{w^n ; n \in \mathbb{N}_+\}$  is dense in $\partial \mathbb D$, where $\mathbb D$ is the open unit disk in $\mathbb C$.

I found this proposition in *Composition operator theory* by Xuxianming (page $47$), which is a book in Chinese.

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that the orbit of an iterated rotation of 0 (by (A)(Pi), A irrational) around a circle centered at the origin is dense in the circle.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282102/prove-that-the-orbit-of-an-iterated-rotation-of-0-by-api-a-irrational-aro)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think they are almost the same. But the answer in this question is kind of "geometric". And I prefer a proof which is more algebraic.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Prove that
$a_n=an\mod 2\pi$ is dense in $(0,2\pi)$ when $\frac{a}{2\pi}\notin \Bbb Q$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have solved it by proving that $\{m+n\alpha | m,n \in \mathbb{Z}, \alpha \notin \mathbb{Q} \}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Yes. Thanks for the complements.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!